# Получить индекс элемента json (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, index

```
var articles = {
"Bootstrap": [
{"id":"1", "title":"Введение"},
{"id":"2", "title":"Как установить"},
{"id":"3", "title":"Сетка"}
],
"JavaScript": [
{"id":"4", "title":"Основы"},
{"id":"5", "title":"Выборка элементов"}
]  
};

$.each(articles,function(key,data) {
console.log('Раздел' + /*что-то*/ +': ' + key);
$.each(data, function(index,value) {
console.log('Статья' + (index+1) + ': id = ' + value['id'] + '; Название = 
'+ value['title']);
});
});

// Результат:
//   Раздел: Bootstrap
//   Статья1: id = 1; Название = Введение
//   Статья2: id = 2; Название = Как установить
//   Статья3: id = 3; Название = Сетка
//   Раздел: JavaScript
//   Статья1: id = 4; Название = Основы
//   Статья2: id = 5; Название = Выборка элементов
```

Вместо /*что-то*/ нужно вставить порядковый номер элемента. Аналогично, как в массиве с index в примере выше.
Чтобы в результате было:

```
//   Раздел 1: Bootstrap
//   Статья: id = 1; Название = Введение
//   Статья: id = 2; Название = Как установить
//   Статья: id = 3; Название = Сетка
//   Раздел 2: JavaScript
//   Статья: id = 4; Название = Основы
//   Статья: id = 5; Название = Выборка элементов
```

Почему-то ни с i=0 и дальнейшим i++ , ни $(this).index() не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно найти индекс ключа в массиве ключей:

```
(Object.keys(articles).indexOf(key)+1)
```

```js
var articles = {
  "Bootstrap": [
    {"id":"1", "title":"Введение"},
    {"id":"2", "title":"Как установить"},
    {"id":"3", "title":"Сетка"}
  ],
  "JavaScript": [
    {"id":"4", "title":"Основы"},
    {"id":"5", "title":"Выборка элементов"}
  ]  
};

$.each(articles,function(key,data) {
  console.log('Раздел ' + 
    (Object.keys(articles).indexOf(key)+1) + 
    ': ' + key);
  $.each(data, function(index,value) {
    console.log('Статья' + (index+1) + ': id = ' + value['id'] + '; Название = '+ value['title']);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Имеет смысл закешировать массив ключей вне цикла `each`:

```
var keys = Object.keys(articles);
```

Или даже заранее составить карту индексов:

```
var i = 0, keymap = Object.keys(articles).reduce(function(carry, key){
  carry[key] = ++i;
}, {});
```

```js
var articles = {
  "Bootstrap": [
    {"id":"1", "title":"Введение"},
    {"id":"2", "title":"Как установить"},
    {"id":"3", "title":"Сетка"}
  ],
  "JavaScript": [
    {"id":"4", "title":"Основы"},
    {"id":"5", "title":"Выборка элементов"}
  ]  
};

var i = 0, keymap = Object.keys(articles).reduce(function(carry, key){
  carry[key] = ++i;
  return carry;
}, {});

$.each(articles,function(key,data) {
  console.log('Раздел ' + 
    (keymap[key]) + 
    ': ' + key);
  $.each(data, function(index,value) {
    console.log('Статья' + (index+1) + ': id = ' + value['id'] + '; Название = '+ value['title']);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз то, что нужно!